# Links truncated in chat

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks

Long links in multiline chat messages will be truncated using (show full text...). This will cause the link to point to the wrong address (namely, it will truncate the location of the link and the text shown in the message by the link). [Example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39254943#39254943) (you may need to enter the room and go to that message for it to truncate). This is easily solvable by just clicking (show full text...), but I don't think links should behave this way. [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?